# Copy and paste text with image. Specifically, paste to the browser

Tags: libreoffice, copy-and-paste

When I copy and paste a text from libreoffice, if the text contains images,  images do not show up.

I am copying from libreoffice  writer  and pasting in various webpages,  such is this site,  gmail,  and  other foruns.

I don't expect that there is an easy fix for libreoffice. Is there? I also wonder if there is any software that would allow this. For me to open a text with images and copy and paste to webpage. I don't mind having to convert or even rewrite the file once, but then I wish to copy and paste without any manual editing, without copying images separately.

Comment: I can think of two formats that can work between LibreOffice and web browsers: 1. Export the page in pdf format (as a pdf file). Such a file can be read by most web browsers; 2. Create an picture (screendump or simply an image/picture of the window shown by LibreOffice), and let your web browser use that image/picture (in this second case the text will also be part of the picture, and maybe you don't want that).